# pig custom function to load multiple character ^^ (double carrot) delimiter

Tags: hadoop, load, apache-pig

I am new to PIG, can some one help me how can I load a file with multiple characters (in my case '^^') as a column delimiter.

for example i have file with following columns
aisforapple^^bisforball^^cisforcat^^disfordoll^^andeisforelephant
fisforfish^^gisforgreen^^hisforhat^^iisforicecreem^^andjisforjar
kisforking^^lisforlion^^misformango^^nisfornose^^andoisfororange

### Regards

Answer (score 2):

Regex is best suited for these kind of multiple characters

```
input.txt
aisforapple^^bisforball^^cisforcat^^disfordoll^^andeisforelephant
fisforfish^^gisforgreen^^hisforhat^^iisforicecreem^^andjisforjar
kisforking^^lisforlion^^misformango^^nisfornose^^andoisfororange

PigScript
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)\\^\\^(.*)\\^\\^(.*)\\^\\^(.*)\\^\\^(.*)')) AS (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5);
DUMP B;

Output:
(aisforapple,bisforball,cisforcat,disfordoll,andeisforelephant)
(fisforfish,gisforgreen,hisforhat,iisforicecreem,andjisforjar)
(kisforking,lisforlion,misformango,nisfornose,andoisfororange)
```

**Explanation:**

```
For better understanding i break the regex into multiple lines
(.*)\\^\\^ ->Any character match till ^^ and stored into f1,(double backslash for special characters) 
(.*)\\^\\^ ->Any character match till ^^ and stored into f2,(double backslash for special characters) 
(.*)\\^\\^ ->Any character match till ^^ and stored into f3,(double backslash for special characters) 
(.*)\\^\\^ ->Any character match till ^^ and stored into f4,(double backslash for special characters) 
(.*)       ->Any character match till the end of string and stored into f5
```